# Prove the function $f(x)=x+\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-continuity

I'm asked to prove $f(x)=x+\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is uniformly continuous in $(1,\infty)$.
I extended the continuity to $[1,\infty)$ aiming for an incoming use of Cantor's theorem on a function defined over a closed interval. To do so I had to show the derivative is bounded and it didn't go well, I kept going back into the loop of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ limit.

Comment: You don't _have_ to show the derivative is bounded. $x\mapsto \sqrt[3]x$ is uniformly continuous on the whole real line, yet its derivative is unbounded near the origin.

Comment: You can use $\frac{{\sin x}}{x} = \int_0^1 {\cos (tx)\,{\rm d}t}$ to show $$
\left| {\frac{{\sin x}}{x} - \frac{{\sin y}}{y}} \right| \le \frac{1}{2}\left| {x - y} \right|.
$$

Comment: @Arthur I wanted to split the domain into two separate intervals. First of all I wanted to show that the derivative diverges to $\infty$ and thus is bounded starting from a certain point M. Hence, in the interval $[M,\infty)$ the derivative is bounded and thus $f$ is UC. To complete the proof, it's immediate that $f$ is UC over $[0,M]$ since it's continuous.

Comment: @Gary I appreciate it a lot! But I'm taking real analysis and integrations aren't in the syllabus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)-x=\frac {\sin x} x$ is continuous and tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. This implies that $f(x)-x$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$. [Thanks to Ennar for providing a link for this implication in the comment below].  Sum of two uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous, so $f(x)=[f(x)-x]+x$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Where can I find a proof for " A continuous function  $f: [a,\infty] \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$"?

Comment: That has been proved many times on MSE. The limit need not be $0$. As long  as there is a finite limit at $\infty$ you get uniform continuity.  @Aria

Comment: I thought of a proof, and I'll be posting it for verification. @geetha290krm

Comment: @Aria, for example, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/997521/122131).

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks a lot for the informative answer!.